# Android ListView onOverScrolled and onOverScroll never be called on 2.3

Tags: android, android-listview

I make custom listview

```
public class BounceListView extends ListView{
...
    @Override
    protected void onOverScrolled(int scrollX, int scrollY, boolean clampedX, boolean clampedY) {
        LOG.d("onOverScrolled");

}

@Override
    protected boolean overScrollBy(int deltaX, int deltaY, int scrollX,
            int scrollY, int scrollRangeX, int scrollRangeY,
            int maxOverScrollX, int maxOverScrollY, boolean isTouchEvent) {
            LOG.d("overScrollBy");
    }

}
```

I never get the log to be output which means this function never been called, while this listview is actually overscrolled.I will really be grateful to hear your idea.

This problem only on 2.3 Android

**UPD:** Ok, i did it and share code on [Github](https://github.com/Suvitruf/Android-sdk-examples/tree/master/OverScrollListView).

Works fine on 2.3+

Comment: Did you try [this](http://jasonfry.co.uk/blog/android-overscroll-revisited/) ?

Comment: As i said, overScrollBy never called on 2.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i did it and share code on [Github](https://github.com/Suvitruf/Android-sdk-examples/tree/master/OverScrollListView).

Works fine on 2.3+