# Android overscroll for ScrollView

Tags: android, scrollview, android-scrollview

I [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22790547/android-listview-onoverscrolled-and-onoverscroll-never-be-called-on-2-3) before about OverScroll in ListView. Default overScroll doesn't work on many devices (for ex.: Samsung Galaxy 2, HTC One X). So I made [OverScrollListView](https://github.com/Suvitruf/Android-sdk-examples/tree/master/OverScrollListView)

But now needed to do the same for `ScrollView`. I made the trick for top overscroll (by using positive number in `overScrollBy`). But when i'm trying to do the same for bottom (by using a negative number in `overScrollBy`), overscroll ScrollView scrolling to top position.

Can someone say why?

P.S. I also tried [this](https://github.com/EverythingMe/OverScrollView/blob/master/src/me/everything/android/widget/OverScrollView.java). But even in top (or bottom) position scrollbar indicator shown somewhere in middle.
This confuse the user...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, i think i did it.

But it's really strange.

I had method for overscroll that i call in ACTION_MOVE:

```
private void pullDown(int deltaY, int lastY) {
    overScrollBy(0, mSlowEffect ? (int)getOverScrollYWithSlow(deltaY) : deltaY, 0, lastY, 5, 5, 0, mMaxYOverscrollDistance, true);
}
```

For ListView for overscroll i just set deltaY something like `pullDown(lastScroll, 0);`

It works for both: top and bottom overscroll.

But for ScrollView it doesn't work for bottom overscroll. So we should send to this method also current scrollY position, something like `pullDown(lastScroll , lastY);`

I share whole code on [Github](https://github.com/Suvitruf/Android-sdk-examples/tree/master/OverscrollView), if someone interested.